# XPath Query always returns NULL only on some queries in SingleNodeSelect

Tags: c#, xpath, null, selectsinglenode

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<users>
  <user number="0772247157">
    <step stepnumber="1">complete</step>
    <step stepnumber="2">complete</step>
    <step stepnumber="3">complete</step>
  </user>
  <user number="0772247158">
    <step stepnumber="1">complete</step>
    <step stepnumber="2">complete</step>
  </user>
  <user number="0772247159">
    <step stepnumber="1">complete</step>
  </user> 
</users>
```

Queries such as

`//user[@number='0772243950']` and `//user[@number=0772243950]/step[last()]` works without any trouble which uses SelectSingleNode method.

However the following function ALWAYS returns null. It works perfectly with XPath Visualizer and i double checked with an online XPath evaluator.

```
public bool checkStepExists(string Number, string StepNumber)
{
    string XPathQuery = "//user[@number=" + Number + "]/step[@stepnumber=" + StepNumber + "]";

    XmlNode Search = SettingsFile.SelectSingleNode(XPathQuery);      

    if (Search == null)
       return false;
    else
       return true;            
}
```

I searched on SO before asking this question and all points to namespace problems. But what I can't understand is that this is a local XML file which does not have a namespace. OR, should I ALWAYS have a namespace and a prefix and use it?

Comment: What values do you pass into that `checkStepExists` method that return a NULL value??

Comment: XML namespace has nothing to do with whether a XML file is local or not. The XML namespace is something inside the file - local or remote. If you have an XML namespace on the XML file, you have to take it into account and pay attention to it. But if you don't have any XML namespace, you cannot just "have one to be safe" - either you have one and respect it, or you don't have any and don't need it

Comment: Sorry guys, it was actually a stupid mistake on my side. I had two versions of the XML file and in 1 version i had the it named "stepnumber" and the other just "number" and i was querying the incorrect XML file. They almost looked the same. My apologies :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your string `XPathQuery` I think you need to quote the numbers.
Like this:

```
string XPathQuery = "//user[@number=\"" + Number + "\"]/step[@stepnumber=\"" + StepNumber + "\"]";
```

Comment: Marking phil's answer as it actually helped me to find the error :)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try it with the extra quotes?

```
string XPathQuery = "//user[@number='" + Number + "']/step[@stepnumber='"
          + StepNumber + "']";
```

I would also be interested in checking if there is any whitespace adding around `Number` or `StepNumber`. Basically: what is the **actual** string query you pass in? (after concatenation etc).

Comment: Actually XPath seems to be forgiving whether the ' ' were included or not. Talk about SQL :P